# Can certain medications cause false positives for COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, blood-tests

I was told by some colleagues at work that certain medications if they were taken by a person can cause antibody COVID-19 tests to test positive, is it possible ?

If so how is that possible ?

Comment: Did you ask your colleagues?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject. We won't address things unnamed people say.